# SqlAlchemy How to add this class to database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a class, that has an array of another class like this

```
class Episode :
  def __init__(self, t, l) :
    self.title = t
    self.link = l

class Show :
  episodes = [] 
  def__init__(self,m)
   self.title = m.title 
   self.description = m.description 
   self.image = m.image
```

the show object ends up with a list of episode objects, I can't figure out how to add it to a database using sqlAlchemy, how should I format the class, like

```
class Show : 
 __tablename__ = 'shows' 
 title = Column(UnicodeText()) 
 image = Column(UnicodeText())
 description = Column(UnicodeText())

 episodes = Column( ????? )
```

and I figure I have to use the [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) feature, just not sure how

I'm new to database programming

any help is really appreciated thanks!

**Edit**

in this example, the child is getting the parent's id, but I need the Show to have a list of episodes with their title and link

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

would I do it like this?

```
class Show(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'shows'
    title = Column(UnicodeText())
    image = Column(UnicodeText())
    description = Column(UnicodeText())
    episodes = Column(Array ??? , ForeignKey('episodes'))

class Episode(Base) :
    __tablename__= 'episodes'
    title = Column(UnicodeText())
    link = Column(UnicodeText())
    children = relationship("Show")
```

Comment: You'll need to use one-to-many relation. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#one-to-many

Comment: is the Show the parent or child?
`code`
    class Show(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'shows'
    title = Column(UnicodeText())
    image = Column(UnicodeText())
    description = Column(UnicodeText())
    episodes = relationship("Episode") 
`code`
??

Comment: You'll need to define foreignkey in Episode on Show. Show is parent in this case. Your code is correct for Show.

Comment: how would episode look, 
`code`
class FinalEpisode(Base) :
    __tablename__= 'episodes'
    title = Column(UnicodeText())
    link = Column(UnicodeText())
    parent_episodes = Column(Array, ForeignKey('shows.episodes')
`code`

Comment: I don't understand your goal. While having foreignkey in child on parent you can for each parent fetch list of related childs.

Comment: I need to put a list of Show objects (and their lists of Episode objects) into a database. Every Show object has a list of 30+ Episode objects that all have a title and link.

Comment: I understand that, and example with parent and child covers your needs. `Parent` has `children` field - list of related `Child` objects. If you are not sure what exactly does foreign key do, please check this http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561 . As for `Show` and `Episode`, you'll put Show object into database, and then for all of Show's Episodes you'll put them in Episode table with foreign key to this Show object.

Comment: Hey thanks!! I got it now, that article helped

Answer (score 0):

I think the best place to start is with the SqlAlchemy introduction on building relationships between tables -- directly along the lines of pavel_form's comment.

The result would be a code that looks something like this:

```
class Show(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Show'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
   episodes = relationship("Episodes", order_by "Episodes.id", backref = 'Show')

   def __init__(self, episodes):
       self.episodes = episodes

class Episodes(Base):
    ___tablename__ = 'Episodes'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
   show_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Show.id'))

   def __init__(self, show_id)
```

You would thus create the Show first followed by individual episodes.  Importantly, when you create the Episodes you must reference the "show_id", i.e. the primary key of the Show that you are referencing, in the creation of the episode.

Doing so would like you call

```
ExampleShow.episodes
```

> > > (1,2,3,4)

Those numbers are the episode primary_key numbers.  You can, of course, change how ExampleShow.episodes reports back the ids when called by adding

```
def __repr__(self):
    return XYZ
```

to the Episode class.  XYZ has to be a Column within the class, and mapped, but it could be episode names, for example. Then punching in ExampleShow.episodes would return ('Name1', 'Name2', etc)